# Dynamic equilibrium of Girard T-derivatized oxysterols

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, chromatography, mass-spectrometry

This is a question relating to organic chemistry, moreso than chromatography.

I am running LC-MS on various hydroxycholesterols (HC) and dihydroxycholesterols (diHC). To increase ionization efficiency with the electrospray, I derivatize my oxysterols with Girard T reagent. The picture below shows the two forms, syn and anti, that the derivatized oxysterols take (here showing derivatized 7α,24S-dihydroxycholesterol).

[image]

It is common knowledge that these isomers often have different retention times through an LC column, leading to split peaks. Some of my oxysterols do show splitting, but my group believes this not to be caused by the syn/anti-situation, as they claim the stationary phase I am using (phenylhexyl from ACE) does not show this. Rather, they say it is probably  contamination of our standards (perhaps of some precursor).

I have observed that the split peaks converge when column temperature is increased. Below is a chromatogram of 7α,24S-diHC splitting at 40 C, but becomes a single broad peak at 70 C. This is consistently true for all my diHCs, but only one (22R-HC) of my HCs (the rest show no splitting at 40 C).
[image]

The mobile phase moving the oxysterols along is around 67% water, 26.7% acetonitrile and 6.3 % methanol. The pH is 2.8 via 0.1 % formic acid.

**My question is this: Could there be a dynamic/active equilibrium ongoing between the syn and anti conformations**, or is this unlikely given the presumably rigid hydrazone bond? This could, perhaps, explain the "bridge" between the two split peaks.

Comment: What were the reading of MS for two peaks at 40 C? That would easily tell you if they are geometric isomers.

Comment: It is also possible that peak at 20.08 min would be belongs to unreacted Girard T hydrazine. Temperature might affected its retention time more effectively than that of hydrazone.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne The chromatogram shown is with selected reaction monitoring (SRM) for a specific fragment from the derivatized oxysterols (530.432->471.358). Both peaks are the same exact mass. 

It shouldn't be the unreacted Girard T, both because of the SRM, and because I'm using a setup where I load the oxysterols onto an SPE, flush it with water to remove excess Girard T reagent to waste, then switch and elute the oxysterols to the column with organic solvent.

Comment: Also, regarding them being potential geometric isomers, usually I would agree, but it is still possible for the split peak to be some precursor used in the production of the oxysterol that for some reason happens to have the same m/z (using a triple quad. resolution isn't the highest)